# How do I combine a bootstrap carousel with a sidebar menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a lot of time creating a sidebar that is flush with my current bootstrap carousel. Here's what my current site looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIU8a.png

And here's what I'm trying to achieve after a user clicks the media object button:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu6Og.png

I've been trying to do this for a while now and the sidebar always ends up moving the picture down, on top of the arrows, or completely behind the carousel. Can someone help with this or show me a template that achieves this?

Also this is a single plage design so if you also know of a way for the sidebar to basically remain frozen on the left side of the page no matter what part of the site you are on, please tell me!

Thanks

Edit: The site, materializecss, is kind of is what I'm aiming for. I don't even really care about the media object button.

Edit 2: So I'm using this carousel and this one page template

http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/full-slider/
http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/scrolling-nav/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title></title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/full-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/scrolling-nav.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>   

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->



</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
   <!-- Navigation -->



    <!-- Full Page Image Background Carousel Header -->
    <div class="navmenu navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-left">
    <a class="navmenu-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    <ul class="nav navmenu-nav">
        <li><a href="../navmenu/">Slide in</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navmenu-push/">Push</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="./">Reveal</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-offcanvas/">Off canvas navbar</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navmenu-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu navmenu-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="canvas">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-recalc="false" data-target=".navmenu" data-canvas=".canvas"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
   <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/cats" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/business" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/abstract" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/transportation" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Intro Section -->
 <!--    <section id="intro" class="intro-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Scrolling Nav</h1>
                    <p><strong>Usage Instructions:</strong> Make sure to include the <code>scrolling-nav.js</code>, <code>jquery.easing.min.js</code>, and <code>scrolling-nav.css</code> files. To make a link smooth scroll to another section on the page, give the link the <code>.page-scroll</code> class and set the link target to a corresponding ID on the page.</p>
                    <a class="btn btn-default page-scroll" href="#about">Click Me to Scroll Down!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section> -->

    <!-- About Section -->
    <section id="photos" class="about-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Photos section</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Services Section -->
    <section id="projects" class="services-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Projects Section</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Contact Section -->
    <section id="recognition" class="contact-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Recognition Section</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>

    <!-- Services Section -->
    <section id="teammembers" class="services-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Team Members Section</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- About Section -->
    <section id="contact" class="about-section">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1>Contact Section</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
<!-- Responsive iFrame -->
<div class="Flexible-container">
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3326.973484035864!2d-111.93373599999995!3d33.50206699673241!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x872b749e6453718b%3A0x2efd3ce15e57a886!2sNorris+Architects+LLC!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1432435089092" width="1300" height="600" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe></div>  
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1>Full Slider by Start Bootstrap</h1>
                <p>The background images for the slider are set directly in the HTML using inline CSS. The rest of the styles for this template are contained within the <code>full-slider.css</code>file.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <hr>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </footer>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Script to Activate the Carousel -->
    <script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 0 //changes the speed
    })
    </script>

    <!-- Scrolling Nav JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/scrolling-nav.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</body>

</html>




    .carousel-inner > .item > img,
    .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
        width: 70%;
        margin: auto;
    }
    html, body {
      height: 100%;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 15px;
    }
    .navmenu {
      z-index: 1;
    }
    .canvas {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0!important;
      z-index: 2;
      min-height: 100%;
      padding: 50px 0 0 0;
      background: #fff;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block; 
    }
    .navbar {
        right: auto;
        background: none;
        border: none;
    }
    .container-fluid {
        padding: 0px;
    }

/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Scrolling Nav HTML Template (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

@media(min-width:767px) {
    .navbar {

        -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
        transition: background .5s ease-in-out,padding .5s ease-in-out;
    }

    .top-nav-collapse {
        padding: 0;
    }

}

/* Demo Sections - You can use these as guides or delete them - the scroller will work with any sort of height, fixed, undefined, or percentage based.
The padding is very important to make sure the scrollspy picks up the right area when scrolled to. Adjust the margin and padding of sections and children 
of those sections to manage the look and feel of the site. */

.intro-section {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
}

.about-section {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #eee;
}

.services-section {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fff;
}

.contact-section {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #eee;
}

/* Flexible iFrame */

.Flexible-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.Flexible-container iframe,   
.Flexible-container object,  
.Flexible-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried www.google.com ?  This isn't a "build my project for me" site, this is a "help me when I'm stuck" site.  Perhaps you would get an answer if you provided your code, showing what you've tried so far and pointing out where you're stuck.

Comment: add a piece of code so we can see what is going wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jasny Bootstrap](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/) has a [great offcanvas menu plugin](https://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/examples/navmenu-reveal/). Using that example with a couple of modifications and [this example carousel](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp), I came up with this

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/o7ms8dny/2/))

CSS

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
    width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.navbar-toggle {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.navmenu {
  z-index: 1;
}
.canvas {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0!important;
  z-index: 2;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0 0 0;
  background: #fff;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    display: block; 
}
.navbar {
    right: auto;
    background: none;
    border: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="navmenu navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-left">
    <a class="navmenu-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    <ul class="nav navmenu-nav">
        <li><a href="../navmenu/">Slide in</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navmenu-push/">Push</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="./">Reveal</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-offcanvas/">Off canvas navbar</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navmenu-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu navmenu-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="canvas">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-recalc="false" data-target=".navmenu" data-canvas=".canvas"> <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            </ol>
            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/cats" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/business" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/abstract" />
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/460/345/transportation" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then make sure to include these files if you haven't included them already

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/js/jasny-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasny-bootstrap/3.1.3/css/jasny-bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```